# how do you use stripe connect to pay sellers

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

for example, the price of the products will vary and will be stored in the database (mongoDB), so is it possible to take the payment from the customer and then give 20% to my account and 80% to the seller. (my app uses nodejs and an express server with mongoDB)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to provide a detailed answer, but here is some advice.

There are three different [types of charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types) when working with connected accounts, and the documentation for each type explains how to collect application fees:

1. Direct charges: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees
2. Destination charges: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#application-fee or https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#transfer-amount
3. Separate charges and transfers: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#collecting-fees

The above processes rely on an amount being provided to collect application fees, so you'll likely need to calculate what 20% of the transaction is on your server and then pass that information into the Stripe flow.

The flow also changes a bit if you're working with Subscriptions instead of one-time payments.  You'd use the `application_fee_percent` parameter:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-application_fee_percent